# firebase error (child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']

Tags: swift, firebase

I am uploading key value pairs to firebase and I am receiving the error

> (child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']...

does this error mean the child "key" contains  $ # . etc

or is it if the child "value" contains $ # . etc?

as I am trying to locate where the error is?

this is my dictionary below though i can't see any of the values in the key part of the key value pair.

this is dictionary:

```
["Subtitle": Sad DVD, "Email": go@mail.com, "Gender": 27, "Username": Sad DVD, "Display Name": Sad DVD, "Account Type": Business, "Password": Sdfsdfsdf, "profileImageUrl": https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/grapevine-2019-1d4a5.appspot.com/o/profile%20images%2F438670B1-E723-484C-8510-555B1CA0B9C5png?alt=media&token=b65796ea-6380-497e-a98b-d1c75c4c454a]
```

this is profile image url https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/grapevine-2019-1d4a5.appspot.com/o/profile%20images%2F438670B1-E723-484C-8510-555B1CA0B9C5png?alt=media&token=b65796ea-6380-497e-a98b-d1c75c4c454a

Comment: the child value which you are accessing that must be non empty and without special characters such as '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']

Comment: ok so you can't store emails? because they would contain an . symbol , I swear on the old firebase database you could but maybe not on the new firestore one?

Comment: that can't be right because you should definitely be able to store a url  , so it must just be the key can't contain these values?

Answer (score 1):

You can store any ascii text as a value so the issue is with one of the keys or perhaps a value is empty.

I copy and pasted your data into a project and enclosed all of the values within quotes

```
let test = ["Subtitle": "Sad DVD",
            "Email": "go@mail.com",
            "Gender": "27",
            "Username": "Sad DVD",
            "Display Name": "Sad DVD",
            "Account Type": "Business",
            "Password": "Sdfsdfsdf",
            "profileImageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/grapevine-2019-1d4a5.appspot.com/o/profile%20images%2F438670B1-E723-484C-8510-555B1CA0B9C5png?alt=media&token=b65796ea-6380-497e-a98b-d1c75c4c454a"
]
```

Then, to test the data I wrote it to Firebase like this:

```
let testRef = self.ref.child("test").childByAutoId()
testRef.setValue(test)
```

Which correctly wrote the data with no errors.

So that would mean the string included in your question is not the actual string being written to Firebase.

I would suggest adding a

```
print(test)
```

right after it's assigned to the test var and inspect that for key's that are incorrect or empty values.

Oh - and the issue could also be the parent node you are attempting to write to. In my code I create the parent key with childByAutoId - you're code isn't included in your question but you may want to check that as well.